# Why createCipheriv and createDecipheriv are not working in separate functions - crypto

Tags: node.js, cryptography

I am starting to use crypto module for my NodeJS project.
My code is simple as below:

```
const { createCipheriv, randomBytes, createDecipheriv } = require('crypto');

const key = randomBytes(32);
const iv = randomBytes(16);
const cipher = createCipheriv('aes256', key, iv);
const decipher = createDecipheriv('aes256', key, iv);

const cipherTest = (message) => {
const encryptedMessage = cipher.update(message, 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex');
const decryptedMessage = decipher.update(encryptedMessage, 'hex', 'utf-8') + decipher.final('utf8');

return decryptedMessage.toString('utf-8')
}
```

The cipherTest function returns the same result as input. Correct!

However, If I create the cipher and decipher functions separately as below , It can not decipher the encryptedMessage.

```
const encryptMessage = (message) => {
const encryptedMessage = cipher.update(message, 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex');
return encryptedMessage;
}

const decryptMessage = (encryptedMessage)  => {
const decryptedMessage = decipher.update(encryptedMessage, 'hex', 'utf-8') + decipher.final('utf8');
return decryptedMessage;
}
```

Could someone have a look? I am so thankful for that.

Comment: You may be using different keys and/or IVs when encrypting and decrypting.

Comment: how are you using it, `randomBytes` creates new keys every time (on the file level..)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ciphers are algorithms, but they contain state. Furthermore, they usually require an IV as input, which needs to be randomized for CBC which is used in this case. That IV needs to change for each ciphertext, assuming that the key remains the same.

As such, you should generally keep to the following structure in pseudo-code:

```
MessageEncryptor {
    Key key
    constructor(Key key) {
         if (key = bad format) {
             throw error // fail fast
         this.key = key
    }
    
    String encryptMessage(String message) {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.Create(key)
        
        Bytes iv = Rng.createBytes(cipher.blockSize)
        cipher.setIV(iv)
        
        Bytes encodedMessage = UTF8.encode(message)

        // lower level runtimes may require padding for CBC mode

        Bytes ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(encodedMessage)
        ciphertext = Bytes.concat(ciphertext, cipher.final())
        
        Bytes ciphertextMessage = Bytes.concat(iv, ciphertext)
        
        // use HMAC here to append an authentication tag

        String encodedCiphertextMessage = Base64.encode(ciphertextMessage)
        return encodedCiphertextMessage
    }
    
    String decryptMessage(String encodedCiphertextMessage) {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.Create(key)
        
        Bytes ciphertextMessage = Base64.decode(encodedCiphertextMessage)

        // use HMAC here to verify an authentication tag

        Bytes iv = Bytes.sub(0, cipher.blockSizeBytes)
        cipher.setIV(iv)
        
        Bytes encodedMessage = cipher.decrypt(ciphertextMessage, start = iv.Size)
        encodedMessage = Bytes.concat(encodedMessage, cipher.final())
        
        // lower level runtimes may require unpadding here

        String message = UTF8.decode(encodedMessage)

        return message
    }
}
```

As you can see it is imperative that you:

- only use the Cipher construct within the method bodies; these object carry state and are generally **not** thread-safe as they are mutable;
- rely on the `key` as a field so that the message encryptor always uses the same key;
- create a new `MessageEncryptor` instance in case you want to use another key;
- create a new IV per message during encryption and extract it from the ciphertext message during decryption.

Notes:

- if your scheme can handle bytes then there is no need to encode the `ciphertextMessage`;
- the IV may have a different size or may not *require* random values for other modes such as GCM;
- using an authenticated mode such as GCM is much safer, but hashing the IV + ciphertext using HMAC is also an option (use a separate key if you are unsure about possible issues for reusing the encryption key);
- `UTF8.encode` and `UTF8.decode` can simply be replaced by **any** other codec in case your message is not a simple string (UTF8 is highly recommended for strings though);
- a lot of libraries will have shortcuts for encoding and such, so your code may be shorter;
- there are also pre-made container formats such as CMS or NaCL which are probably more secure and more flexible than any scheme you can come up with;
- CBC, as used in this example, is vulnerable to plaintext oracle attacks including padding oracle attacks
- for larger messages it makes more sense to use streaming for all encoding,   decoding, encryption and decryption operations (the methods shown here have a high and unnecessary memory requirement);
- create these kind of classes only **for specific types of messages**, and create a protocol + protocol description if you do so; **most crypto API's don't need wrapper classes**, it was created with this kind of flexibility on purpose;

The `MessageEncryptor` still is very lightweight - actually it has only one key as state (sometimes having a an additional key and an algorithm or two as well). If you are going to expand with *fields that can change value or state* such as a buffer then you want to create a **new instance** of the class each time you use it from a different thread. Otherwise you want to clear the state after each successful message encryption / decryption.

You may want to destroy the key securely once you've finished using it.